# RTMP library for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, rtmp, weborb, fluorinefx

I am building a WP7 app to take photo and upload image to a third-party server using RTMP. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any sensible implementation of the RTMP client for Windows Phone 7.

I have downloaded [WebOrb](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html), but it seems like the WebOrb for WP7 library doesn't support RTMP. Furthermore, I cannot integrate the Silverlight dll to my WP7 app.

I also looked at the [FluorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/download.html) but it doesn't have a version for WP7 either.

Can you advise another library which would provide RTMP on WP7, or a way to make the above libraries working with WP7?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if WP7 can run "exe" files but if u can, try with VLC 2.00 "Twoflower" or the [new release](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.0.0.html). The first one works great on PC with RTMP and others.